# sonar java 3.9 false positive resource is not closed (squid:S2095)

Tags: sonarqube

the following code leads to a false positive about the inputstreamreader not being closed. The inputstream reader is afaik closed automatically, if the BufferedReader is closed. I know that this could be solved more elegantly with try with resource with java 7+, but this is part of android code, so we are stuck with this solution. Btw. the example code in the rule recommends to do reader.close (without try catch) which does not work as it throws an IOException.

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(…));
        // …
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // …
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // …
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not redact this as a question targeting SonarSource team. If you want to do things like this, reach out the google groups : sonarqube@google-groups.com 

We do monitor this sonarqube tag but SO is not a website for this, but for asking questions.

Comment: dear benzonico. ok will do!

Comment: wrong email let me correct : sonarqube@googlegroups.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess the point is with the "new InputStreamReader(...)", the "..." probably contains a resource definition that must be closed.
Look at https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO04-J.+Release+resources+when+they+are+no+longer+needed

Comment: it's
     reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(FILE)));

Answer (score 0):

In your case i understand the sonar warning, in my case not:

```
 BufferedWriter csvFile = null;
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
 OutputStreamWriter os = null;
 try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName); // here false SONAR warning
            os = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
            csvFile = new BufferedWriter(os);
 } finally {
            if (csvFile != null) { //NOSONAR
                csvFile.close();
            }

            if (os != null) { //NOSONAR
                os.close();
            }

            if (fos != null) { //NOSONAR
                fos.close();
            }

     }
```